# Make javascript variable can be empty

Tags: javascript

Hi i have this function below that removes duplicates from the variable `suggest` but sometimes the data i receive for the `suggest` variable is empty and the code below wont work beacause of the `JSON.parse` function how do i make it so that the variable accepts empty data so that the code below will still run without any problems. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

```
function suggestData(data){

    var suggest = []; // I tried adding this and setting it to null but it doesn't seem to work.
    suggest = JSON.parse(data);

    for (var i = suggest.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
        for (var j = 0; j < arrString.length; j++) {
            if (suggest[i] === arrString[j]) {
                suggest.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you want to check if data-parameter has value? Did you try finding it on Google or this site, there are numerous answers for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `suggest` inside an `if` condition to check whether data exists or not

```
function suggestData(data){

    var suggest = [];

    if(data){
       suggest = JSON.parse(data);
    }

    for (var i = suggest.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
        for (var j = 0; j < arrString.length; j++) {
            if (suggest[i] === arrString[j]) {
                suggest.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Also you can simply end the function if you do not want to execute it when data is empty:

```
function suggestData(data) {
   if(!data){
      return false;
    }
  //other code here
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `length` conditionally as,

`var length = suggest? suggest.length: 0;`

```js
function suggestData(data){

    var suggest = [];
    suggest = JSON.parse(data);
    var length = suggest? suggest.length: 0;
    for (var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
        for (var j = 0; j < arrString.length; j++) {
            if (suggest[i] === arrString[j]) {
                suggest.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
suggestData(null);
```

Comment: actually i want to make it so that it can JSON.parse a empty string

Comment: @Bobby I did not get that. What do you mean?

Comment: Because this error keeps poping up `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` so im thinking that it cant run because the `suggest` is empty. So what i want to is to try to make the JSON.parse be able to parse a empty string

Answer (score 1):

function suggestData(data){

```
var suggest = []; // I tried adding this and setting it to null but it doesn't seem to work.
```

if(data)
    suggest = JSON.parse(data);

```
for (var i = suggest.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
    for (var j = 0; j < arrString.length; j++) {
        if (suggest[i] === arrString[j]) {
            suggest.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Just add the if condition on parsing line like 
written in above code::

if(data)
    suggest = JSON.parse(data);

Answer (score 1):

The simplest:

```
if(!data || !suggest)
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [1,2,3,8,3,4,4,5]
const removeDuplicateItems = arr => [...new Set(arr)];

console.log(removeDuplicateItems(array))
```

If you just want to remove duplicated items in an array, you can instead try `Set` which is quite handy

Even if `array` is empty or null, this method `removeDuplicateItems` will still works

Comment: @downvoters: How is suggesting another way is consider a bad answer?